# Можно ли эмулировать подключение принтера к LPT-порту и Com-порту если физически он подключен к USB?

Tags: linux, c

Мне нужно научиться читать и писать данные в `LPT`и `COM` порты на `C` `Linux`. Проблема в том, что для чтения нужно устройство подключенное к порту, которое отвечало бы, а принтер у меня подключен к `usb-2.0` Можно ли как-нибудь программно сэмулировать корректную работу этих портов? Занять их программно?

Comment: Воткните в COM заглушку, замыкающую ноги: TX на RX, DTR на DSR и CD, а RTS на CTS. Отвечать не отвечать, но эхо отправленного будете оттуда получать.

Comment: Проще купить адаптер, и к нему уже подключать что-нибудь.

Answer (score 1):

Насчет lpt 25 пинового сложно сэмулировать. Принтер, подключенный к USB можно звести через файл устройства. Например /dev/usb/lp1 или /dev/ttyUSB0. Открываешь их как файл и можно отправлять данные. Для реального ком порта нужно установить скорость и контроль потока.